# Why server socket gives port no which is different from bound port no?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, endianness

I am writing a small socket program in C. In server side I create a socket descriptor using socket() system call, then I am binding that socket with a port. After this I am trying to get the IP/Port no of the descriptor, it gives port no different then the bind port no. I am trying to get back IP/Port using getsockname() method, Is it right to use this method ? Please help me.

```
#define SERVER_ADDR "127.0.0.1"
#define SERVER_PORT "9090" // actual port no I am binding
#define QUEUE_LENGTH 10

int main()
{
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *temp;

memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

// here I am passing SERVER_PORT == 9090
int status = getaddrinfo(SERVER_ADDR,SERVER_PORT,&hints,&servinfo);
if(status != 0)
{
printf("Server: getaddrinfo() errored with code %d\n",status);
return;
}

int sfd = -1;
for(temp = servinfo; temp != NULL; temp = servinfo->ai_next)
{
sfd = socket(temp->ai_family,temp->ai_socktype,temp->ai_protocol);
if(sfd == -1)
{
  printf("Server: Socket error with code %d\n",sfd);
  continue;
}

status = bind(sfd,temp->ai_addr,temp->ai_addrlen);
if(status == -1)
{
  printf("Server: Bind error with code %d\n",status);
  continue;
}
printf("Server: Bind Successful\n");

// un necessary code goes here
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
char ipv4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
int addr_size = sizeof(server_address);
// i am using below method to get the port no from socket descriptor
getsockname(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, &addr_size);

// I am expecting below will print 9090. but it prints different port no why ? 
printf("Server Port: %d\n",server_address.sin_port);
printf("Port from getsddrinfo: %d\n",( (struct sockaddr_in *)temp->ai_addr)->sin_port);

inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(server_address.sin_addr),ipv4,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
printf("Server IP Address: %s\n",ipv4);
// un necessary code ends here
break;
}

if(temp == NULL)
{
printf("Server: Failed to bind\n");
return;
}
status = listen(sfd,QUEUE_LENGTH);
if(status == -1)
{
printf("Server: Listening failed\n");
return;
}
printf("Server: waiting for coneections...\n");

while(1)
{
printf("Server: Main loop, will wait for client to connect...\n");
struct sockaddr client_address;
int addr_length = sizeof client_address;
// accepting client
int new_sfd = accept(sfd,&client_address,&addr_length); 
}
printf("Server: Done!\n"); 
}
```

Output is:

```
Server: Bind Successful
Server Port: 33315 --> why this different from one I have binded (9090)
Port from getsddrinfo: 33315 --> why this different from one I have binded (9090)
Server IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Server: waiting for coneections...
Server: Main loop, will wait for client to connect...
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `for(temp = servinfo; temp != NULL; temp = servinfo->ai_next)` read `for(temp = servinfo; temp != NULL; temp = temp->ai_next)`?

Comment: You are correct, even after modification still I am getting different port no. Thanks.

Comment: And please indend your code properly, it's hard to read like this.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow and this is my first question, I will do properly in future. Thanks alk :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The decimal members of `struct sockaddr` are returned in network byte order.

So you need to convert such values to host byte order, using the `ntoh` family of functions before using them, printing them.

Comment: I changed the print statement to `printf("Server Port: %d\n",ntohs(server_address.sin_port));`, now I am getting correct port no 9090. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: @DhanarajDurairaj: Be sure to accept the answer so alk gets credit for it.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: As per alk's answer only I made the change in my program. I didn't get your point here ?

Comment: @DhanarajDurairaj: if alk's answer addresses your question, then mark it as the accepted answer so he gets the appropriate reputation points for it.

Answer (score 1):

add `hints.sin_port = htons( 9090 );`after `hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;`

Comment: It does not make sense in the OP's context to set the port in `hints` as it will be overwritten by `getaddrinfo()` anyway. I assume `getaddrinfo()` already fill `hints`'s members up using the correct byte order (network).

Comment: ooops, I was thinking in getservbyname(), sorry

Comment: hints is type of `struct addrinfo' there is no direct member `sin_port`. As alk told getaddrinfo() will fill the servinfo's members in network byte order. May be like `( (struct sockaddr_in *)servinfo->ai_addr )->sin_port = htons(9090);`. Am I correct?

Comment: You're right sin_port is a direct member of struct sockaddr_in

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` takes host and service (for IP4 that is: a hostname or its IP address and a port number, both in ASCII representation) to return one or more ready filled up `struct addrinfo` to be passed to `bind()` (server side) or `connect()` (client side).